# DB Design Table with multiple relationships

Tags: database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a database design where a table is linked either to one or to another table yielding a total of 5 relationships. If the table is linked to table 1, the link to the 4 other tables is NULL. If I used 5 foreign keys, I will have a swiss cheese as a result!

I have table "center" which is either linked to district or canton, or department, or village, or city. If center belongs to district, it can no more belong to canton/department/village/city.

I cannot just have an attribut "center-type" which will show to what the center is linked because I also need to know to which instance of district, canton, etc. it's exactly linked.

Sincerely,

RLO

Comment: I think a better design would be a single foreign key to the center type and another column specifying the center value.  Two columns, both non-null.   I think you're correct in thinking that your proposal takes normalization too far.

Comment: I'm not quite sure to have understood the answer.
The issue is the following.
I have 6 tables (entities): center, district, canton, department, village, city.
The relationships are as follows:
center -> district (for a center which is within a district)
center -> canton (for a center within a canton)
center ->  department (for a center within a departement)
center -> city (for a center within a city)
center ->  village (for a center within a village)

If I create table center_type, "center_type" will need to be linked to canton, village, city, department...*

Comment: Sounds like a bad design.

Comment: Please edit your comments into your question. Please give the *meaning* of each table (in terms of columns), ie the associations they represent. The kinds of "relationships" you are describing are *not* FKs, they are merely *like* FKs. A FK just says a value in some columns must appear in others. All constraints including FKs *follow* from the association/table meanings & the possible values they can have given what situations can arise. These complex inclusions are almost certainly the result of a poor choice of associations/tables and consequent constraints vs a more straightforward design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113122/conditional-foreign-key-relationship/114281#114281

What you can have is a *Center* table consisting of the data that is common to village, city and so forth. This includes the ID of the center and an indicator of which kind of center it is: City, Canton, Village, District or Department. Then a separate table for each kind of center with a PK that is also a FK back to the *Center* table.

So all entities that must have a relationship to a center has a FK to the *Center* table which tells you what kind of center it is and thus which other table holds additional information about the center.

Comment: My English wasn't good enough, sorry. This answer sounds good. My understanding of it is that:
I would have 5 intermediary tables (district_center, city_center, village_center, etc.).
The FKs of these respecitve tables will refer to the table center.
This way, I will know to which village/city/district, etc. the center belongs.
There will be no FK in the center table.
The FKs in the intermediary tables will give access to the additional information (either in city/village/district, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may have both, the attribute "center-type" (which identifies which type of center you're dealing with), and an id attribute (let's say "idCenter"), which links the id of the instance of the center type, and which the combination of both will tell you the exact type of center and the instance of the center type linked.

Center-type and idCenter are Foreign Keys (so this way you will have 2 FK and not 5).

EDIT: Actually this answer has redundancy. It would be better to create a single FK for each of the tables that are not center. For example, table district would have the following attributes:

disctrict(id_district, id_center, ...).

Table village would be:

village(id_village, id_center,...).

In all cases, id_center is a FK to center. This way, you will know, for each center, to what "center-type" it belongs to (throw the FK).

Comment: I'm not quite sure to have understood the answer.
The issue is the following.
I have 6 tables (entities): center, district, canton, department, village, city.
The relationships are as follows:
center -> district (for a center which is within a district)
center -> canton (for a center within a canton)
center ->  department (for a center within a departement)
center -> city (for a center within a city)
center ->  village (for a center within a village)

Comment: would it be good practice to use intermediate entities to link center either to district, canton, department, city, or village?
I would have the following additional tables: district_center (for centers that are linked to disctricts), city_center (centers linked to cities), canton_center (centers linked to cantons), etc.

Comment: That practice would be good if we were talking about a "many to many" relationship. In here, we are talking about a "belongs to" relationship, where a center belongs to a village, or a district, etc.

The strictly correct answer is create a single FK for each of the tables that are not center. For example, table district would have the following attributes:
disctrict(id_district, id_center, ...).
Table village would be:
village(id_village, id_center,...).
In all cases, id_center is a FK to center.

This way, you will know, for each center, to what "center-type" it belongs (throw the FK).

Comment: The first answer I gave you has redundancy